# use Eclipse to edit source code file on virtual machine

Tags: eclipse, debugging, sublimetext2, virtual-machine, samba

Currently I'm using a virtual machine (VM) environment on my laptop (Mac) for project development (i.e. virtual machine is running in VirtualBox on my laptop).

And I just use Samba to open code folder (on VM) and then I use SubLime (on my laptop) to connect to VM, so that I can edit code files (located on VM) from my laptop.

But I found SubLime is not efficient when I want heavy debugging for Java, so I would like to use Eclipse on my laptop, to edit and debug code files located on VM.

I tried to google but didn't find useful information, could you please tell me how to use Eclipse on my laptop, to open project on virtual machine?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can treat your virtual machine as a **remote machine**, then problem is solved.

1. Install the "Remote System Explorer" program for Eclipse
2. List item
3. Install the package on the desired programming language
4. Connection to the remote server with "Remote System Explorer"
5. Enabling programming language perspective
6. Open new remote project and edit

read here: [**Eclipse - Connect to a remote file system**](http://us.informatiweb.net/tutoriels/148--eclipse-connect-to-a-remote-file-system.html)